# i dont find echo /opt/ros/kinetic/stacks

Tags: ros, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when  installing ROS
i write  $ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in the command line but i dont find
/opt/ros/kinetic/stacks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248958/i-dont-find-echo-/opt/ros/kinetic/stacks/) by [mam](https://answers.ros.org/users/28637/mam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` to fill your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.
However, the `stacks` folder does not exist anymore since hydro, afaik, so even though it has been in the `ROS_PACAKGE_PATH` it did not do anything.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mam](https://answers.ros.org/users/28637/mam/) on 2016-11-28**:
thank you man and i will return back by i video for you that will help you inchallah
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hezcb2YRasM